# Manera limpia de buscar en un objeto contenido en el valor de un mapa

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, map

La pregunta es mucho mas sencilla vista que planteada asique voy a ello , tengo un mapa con la estructura  :

```
Map <String, JugadorSeleccion> jugadores = new TreeMap<String, JugadorSeleccion>();
jugadores.put("Casillas", new JugadorSeleccion(1, "Casillas", "Portero"));
jugadores.put("Ramos", new JugadorSeleccion(15, "Ramos", "Lateral Derecho"));
jugadores.put("Pique", new JugadorSeleccion(13, "Pique", "Central"));
jugadores.put("Puyol", new JugadorSeleccion(5, "Puyol", "Central"));
```

y quiero buscar en ese mapa por ejemplo por la posicion del jugador , pero claro existen solo dos maneras de buscar en un map :

```
jugadores.contains(key); //En este caso String
jugadores.contains(value); //En este caso JugadorSeleccion
```

¿La unica manera de buscar en el mapa por el valor de la posicion del jugador , del objeto jugadorSeleccion seria recorriendo el mapa ?

```
//iterando solo sobre valores
 for (JugadorSeleccion value : map.values()) {
  if(value.getPosicion().equals("Central"){
    //devuelves el nodo
  }
}
```

¡ Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir de Java 8 puedes usar *streams*:

```
Map<String, JugadorSeleccion> resultado = jugadores.entrySet().stream()
                                         .filter( j -> "Central".equals( j.getValue().getPosicion() ) )
                                         .collect( Collectors.toMap( c -> c.getKey(), c -> c.getValue() ) );
```